# how can I create a printable invoice with non-English characters by using any programming language?

Tags: printing, report

I have a program need to create a printable invoice with non-English characters. The invoice contains logos(images), tables and non-English characters(Chinese, Vietnamese). I am using Perl to create PCL file that can be printed. Now I am facing an issue with printing non-English characters. The non-English characters in the PCL file can not be printed correctly.

My question is:
What is an elegant way to create a printable invoice with non-English characters? Any programming language is acceptable. The Library should be compatible with non-English characters. A smooth learning curve is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to put in the time, you could make a template for your invoices in LaTex or just download one. 
For example

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
```

would let you use Chinese characters.